# How insert to javascript to document using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a "badly written" simple banner:

```
...
    <script>
    document.write('banner text')
    </script>
...
```

How to correct insert this banner to document using javascript ?

This code:

```
<div id="id"></div>
$('#id').html('\x3Cscript>document.write("banner text");\x3C/script>')
```

replace all text in document ...

Answer (score 1):

insert HTML:

```
$('#id').html('banner text')
```

or for text only (avoid XSS by escaping mark-up):

```
$('#id').text('banner text')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't in the jquery code.
It's just that calling document.write() after the page has loaded - **it replaces all text in the document**

Try this:

```
$('#id').html("Banner text")
```